# Can't target node to serve static files

Tags: node.js, angular, express, routes, middleware

I'm newbie to nodejs.
I'm trying to target the node to serve the static pages, in the server.js file.
when using the first option:

```
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname +'/site/public/dist/public/', 
{
  index: 'index.html'
}));
```

the site is reached, but when hitting the F5, I get 
Cannot GET /
so, I figured out that there is no "default" routing to load the requested module, 
SO I tried putting "*" instead of the "/":

```
app.use("*", express.static(__dirname +'/site/public/dist/public/', 
{
    index: 'index.html'
}));
```

but is not working.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to serve the `dist` folder using express. put the `dist` in the root of `server.js`. This is expected if you did not define `*` properly. We use `false` in the static file it would not abort the thread. What that means is that `false` will cause the code to continue to execute. So lines of code which appear after the `/`.The `*` will be executed.

**[express.static(root, [options])](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static)**

This is a built-in middleware function in Express. It serves static files and is based on serve-static.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

// serve angular front end files from root path
app.use('/', express.static('dist', { redirect: false }));

// rewrite virtual urls to angular app to enable refreshing of internal pages
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve('dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log("Frontend is started!");
})
```